# SQLite join selection from the same table as two columns

Tags: sqlite

I have one table 'positions' with columns:

> id | session_id | keyword_id | position

and some rows in it:

- 10 rows with session_id = 1
- and 10 with session_id = 2.

As a result of the query I need a table like this:

> id | keyword_id | position1 | position2

where 'position1' is a column with values that had session_id = 1 and 'position2' is a column with values that had session_id = 2.

The result set should contain 10 records.

Sorry for my bad English.

Data examle:

```
id  | session_id | keyword_id | position
1   | 1          | 1          | 2
2   | 1          | 2          | 3
3   | 1          | 3          | 0
4   | 1          | 4          | 18
5   | 2          | 5          | 9
6   | 2          | 1          | 0
7   | 2          | 2          | 14
8   | 2          | 3          | 2
9   | 2          | 4          | 8
10  | 2          | 5          | 19
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that you wish to combine positions with the same id, from the two sessions, then the following query should to the trick:

```
SELECT T1.keyword_id
     , T1.position as Position1
     , T2.position as Position2
  FROM positions T1
       INNER JOIN positions T2
               ON T1.keyword_id = T2.keyword_id  -- this will match positions by [keyword_id]
              AND T1.session_id = 1 
              AND T2.session_id = 2
```

Comment: No, it not works as expected. Result contains 20 records and columns Position1 and Position2 are equal. And I set (T1.session_id = 1              OR T2.session_id = 2) because statement AND in this cause is not correct as I think.

Comment: @udi - can you please post some of the data that you have in the table `positions`?

Comment: Yes, I have tried with AND - the result is empty. Sorry, I did not said about another one column 'keyword_id'. Grouping need to be by this column.

Comment: @udi - I see, so the problem is that you need to do the join on `keyword_id`, not the `id` column since the values in `id` are all different. I'm updating my answer now..

Comment: Great! I'm glad I was able to help!